# Jvm settings on the server side

Tags: jvm, jvm-arguments

About to choose hosting service for a website written in GWT with Java on the server side.
Does anyone have some good guidelines for JVM mem settings. Some hosting services are limiting JVM memory. I was told one JVM per CPU core but what about mem settings?

Best regards,

Niclas Lindberg

Comment: Who told you "one JVM per core"? That's just bad advice.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the input. I was reading up on some other e-commerce open source project were guidelines for deployment was just that. On a two core system use two separate JVMs. It sounded as a good idea - may be some JVM implementations have problems using the full power of multiple cores. Instead having a load balancer splitting the requests to different JVMs to maximize throughput. Can you explain why it is a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple JVM will increase the memory footprint. We used to run single JVM even for 64 core machines. You need to tune your JVM parameters accordingly. 
Please see the following links

http://docs.sun.com/source/817-2180-10/pt_chap5.html
http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/06/6-common-errors-in-setting-java-heap.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the requirements of your app. You can start with a certain size, e.g:

```
 -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

You need to monitor the JVM with JConsole and see if it is good enough. You can adjust the parameters according to your monitor result. Basically, -Xms should be equals with -Xmx which can reduce the CPU overhead for increasing heap size.